# Firebase iOS SDK Crashing with FIRInstallations validateAppOptions:appName

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to develop iOS app on Flutter,

My `pubsec.yaml` file has

```
  firebase_core: 0.4.3+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_database: ^3.1.1
```

Below is the error I get,

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x0000000106000e9f +[FIRInstallations validateAppOptions:appName:] + 799
    4   Runner                              0x00000001060009eb -[FIRInstallations initWithAppOptions:appName:installationsIDController:prefe<…>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add apiKey value to FirebaseOptions on iOS too, it worked for me!

```
FirebaseApp.configure(
   name: 'name',
  options: Platform.isIOS
      ?  const FirebaseOptions(
          googleAppID: '1:xxxx',
          gcmSenderID: 'xxxx',
          databaseURL: 'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com',
          apiKey:'xxx',
        )
      : const FirebaseOptions(
          googleAppID: '1:xxx',
          apiKey: 'xxx',
          databaseURL: 'https://xx.firebaseio.com',
        )
);
```

Comment: You should include a code snippet or example of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that you need to update the GoogleServices-Info.plist from the console to the app.

Full details in the source at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseInstallations/Source/Library/FIRInstallations.m#L122